# Where do these blank spaces come from in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am playing with customizing beamer presentations, and I tried the following code to setup the look and feel of the frame title:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[left, wd = \paperwidth, ht = 1em]{palette frame title}
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
        \textbf{\insertframetitle}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd = \paperwidth, ht = .15em]{palette frame title}
        \rule{\paperwidth}{.15em}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

The result is the following (I have set `bg = yellow` in the palette of the `beamercolorbox` to visualize their dimensions):

[image]

I would appreciate if someone could explain to me where both blank spaces come from: the one above the first `beamercolorbox`, and the one between the two boxes. I have noticed that modifying the height of the boxes seem to alter the size of those blank spaces, which looks like a wierd behavior to me and makes it difficult to locate things accurately.

Comment: The space before "Aloha" comes from the line break between `\usebeamerfont{frametitle}` and `\textbf{\insertframetitle}`. Use `\usebeamerfont{frametitle}%` instead (or delete the line break). But this is probably not your question.

Comment: you should provide an example that produces the pronlem, but you shpuld put `%` at the ends of all those lines. you will have at least `\parskip` glue between the boxes but without seeing any code impossible to say if that is non zero here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the default beamer themes to see how they remove the interlineskip based on the presence of a background colour, see e.g. https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty#L164

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[left,wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \strut\insertframetitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{lower separation line head}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=yellow,fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{titgle}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]